# (perl) how the Terminal (Mac) can locate LWP... in @INC?

Tags: perl, terminal, cpan

I try to run my perl code in the terminal but I have this error appears:

```
Can't locate LWP/Protocol/https.pm in @INC (you may need to install the LWP::Protocol::https module) (@INC contains: /Users/wobot/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-2level /Users/wobot/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/site_perl/5.28.0 /Users/wobot/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/5.28.0/darwin-2level /Users/wobot/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/5.28.0) at projet.pl line 23.
```

I installed the LWP :: Protocol module via cpan but the problem persists.
How to solve that?

Comment: *I installed the LWP :: Protocol module* - LWP::Protocol and LWP::Protocol::https are two separate modules.

Answer (score 2):

Install the module as the error suggests. From the [module documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https):

> The LWP::Protocol::https module provides support for using https schemed URLs with LWP. This module is a plug-in to the LWP protocol handling, so you don't use it directly. Once the module is installed LWP is able to access sites using HTTP over SSL/TLS.

As high-lighted by [Dave Cross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/dave-cross), in his comments, `LWP::Protocol` and `LWP::Protocol::https` are two separate modules, but as the documentation notes, the latter isn't used directly.

Comment: For clarity, you might mention what Dave Cross said in the comments, that they are two different modules, and that he installed one, but not the other.

Comment: @TLP so noted. Thanks.